# highcharts-ng, gauge that can handle negative values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using ng-highcharts and I'm trying to create a gauge that can handle negative values, I have almost got there. However, I want zero to be at the top (in others words, I want the chart to be rotated 90 degrees to the right), and for some reason, the `-200` value is printed twice/overlapping.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/2006/

this is what it should ideally look like, but I want the same thing in ng-highcharts so I can use in my angular application

http://jsfiddle.net/5rncm2nn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating my own directive instead of using ng-highcharts,and its working as expected for me.

Also remove the options object which is wrapping the chart object in your config, that might also be creating problem

Use this config

```
{
        chart: {
          type: 'gauge',
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBackgroundImage: null,
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          plotShadow: false
        },
    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: -200,
        max: 200,
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 200,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, { from: -200,
            to: 0,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}
```

Same as yours just removed the options object

Checkout this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/2010/